# Store data in video frames while capturing the video in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

How to store the data like time or latitude in video frames per second while capturing the video and retrieve this data back from the saved video in iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Most video formats include video MetaData, describing the whole video at the asset level.  When using AVAssetWriter, you can add MetaData items before writing to associate this with the output file. https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avassetwriter#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriter/metadata

There are common keys (https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/1668870-av_foundation_metadata_key_const/1669056-common_metadata_keys) you can use to store the information if you like.

Note this is only at the file level, not per frame.

If you want to store information at a "frames per second" type time refernece then you could build a custom solution, interacting with the buffers "vended" by AVFoundation [Recording locations in time domain with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082670/recording-locations-in-time-domain-with-avfoundation/40097797#40097797) It's possible to then write your own custom storage for that information that's synchronised to the video file and you would need to read it back and process it yourself.

I don't believe there's a way to encapsulate that "per frame location info" within the actual video file itself (you could perhaps do a hack and repurpose a subtitles AVAssetTrack and write the info, then pull it off but not display it - this would be unpredictable when video was played on other devices however).

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

Following on from a comment a year after I wrote this, I did some more investigation.  While you could use and abuse the subtitle track like suggested, a better solution is to use the AVAsset metadata type which is specifically for this.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype/1390709-subtitle

There are many different AVAssetTrack types which allow you to time data to a point on a video including

- Audio
- closedCaption
- depthData (BETA at time of edit)
- metaData <- This is probably what you want
- metaDataObject <- In combination with this one too
- muxed
- text
- timecode
- video

Comment: Thank you for the idea with subtitles! Do you see any pitfalls in writing "custom metadata" as <b>comments</b> in subtitles (say, .vtt)?

Comment: That was a "crazy idea" off the top of my head.  I had a quick look now and there is a better way to do this, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmediatype/1390709-subtitle includes a specific timed metadata type - you'd be better off using this.  You COULD use SubTitles to do it, but the pitfall is that something playing the video back that actually displays subtitles would see garbage.  I'll edit my answer.